# UIImage cropping based on overlay image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Hi i want get the cropped image laying under the overlay image (a small image is placed over background image i need part of background image under the over layed image ) .right now i am using this method

```
//create image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 1.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.size.width/2.0f, rect.size.height/2.0f);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, imageOffset.x, imageOffset.y);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, imageRotation);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -image.size.width/2.0f, -image.size.height/2.0f);

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

//update image
imageScale = 1.0f;
imageRotation = 0.0f;
imageOffset = CGPointZero;
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

//end context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but i need the image which is underlaying the overlay image.

Comment: Is the `image` in `[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];` the background image?

Comment: @Mar0ux  .The overlay image is transparent at center (it is smaller than background image ). some part of background image is visible through the center of  transparent overlay image . The position of background image we can adjust using touches . so after adjusting the position the part of background image portion visible through the center of overlay image ,i need that part .

Comment: Ok, and I assume the overlay image's transparent part is dynamic, so you need to calculate the transparent rect, is that correct? You can go over all the pixels of the overlay image ([this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html) should help) to figure out which part is the transparent part and then you have the rect you need. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure ,but i will check the (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html) url you have given and try .